# Terminate ansible playbook based on shell output

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook that runs a shell command. If there is a specific message in the output, I need to terminate the playbook. Here's what I've tried:

```
- name : Do foo
  shell: /bin/my_application arg1 arg2 arg3
  args:
    creates: /tmp/foo_1
  with_items: data_items
  register: foo_result

- debug: var=foo_result

- debug: var=foo_result
  when:
    - foo_result.results is defined
    - '"[Foo Bar Baz] Err Code abc123" in foo_result.results.stdout'
  failed_when: true
```

The intention here is that *if* '"[Foo Bar Baz] Err Code abc123"' appears in the output of the program, I want to print the *full* output (which includes very useful information, but there is a *lot* of information so I don't want to print it *all* of the time) and then abort the playbook.

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work.

The first debug statement prints something sort of like this:

```
TASK: [do_stuff | debug var=foo_result] **************************** 
ok: [some-node] => {
    "foo_result": {
        "changed": true, 
        "msg": "All items completed", 
        "results": [
            {
                "changed": true, 
[Snip..]
                "stderr": "", 
                "stdout": "Very large stack trace containing [Foo Bar Baz] Err Code abc123"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

So, I know that the error message I'm interested in *is* in `stdout`.

But the second one prints this:

```
TASK: [do_stuff | debug var=foo_result] **************************** 
fatal: [some-node] => error while evaluating conditional: "[Foo Bar Baz] Err Code abc123" in foo_result.results.stdout
```

I've also tried this using `foo_result.stdout`, and also escaping the `[` and `]` as `\[` and `\]` in the condition, and I've tried testing that `foo.results.stdout is defined`, and I'm not sure why I'm getting this conditional evaluation error for all these permutations. I would have expected a syntax error or something... Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do here (fail when there's specific text in a command's stdout and then print that stdout)?

*(Ansible version is 1.6.10)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had some kind of syntax errors in the tasks yml file, but they weren't reported as "syntax error".

The problem seemed to be how I was "and"-ing conditions. I thought I could list them separately, but it seems that's not the case.

This task:

```
- debug: var=foo_result
  when:
    - foo_result.results is defined and "[Foo Bar Baz] Err Code abc123" in foo_result
```

Doesn't give me any errors. Ansible is not returning an error on this code, but the condition always evaluates to "true". however, I think that is a different problem, and I'll post a new question for that.

---

I've posted a follow-up question here: [Ansible condition always evaluates to false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28882891/ansible-condition-always-evaluates-to-false)

Answer (score 2):

You only need to change the third task:

```
- debug: var=foo_result
  failed_when: "'[Foo Bar Baz] Err Code abc123' in foo_result.stdout"
```

Works for me with ansible 1.8.4!

Comment: From what I can tell, the main difference is that you swapped the single quotes for double quotes. I tried this but got the same error (except with different quotes). Mind you, we're using Ansible 1.6.10...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner you should mention your Ansible in the original question. 1.6 is extremely old. You should really put effort into upgrading.

Comment: @Mxx: Yes, upgrading would be nice, but will probably have to wait. I think I resolved the issue I originally posted, but new issues have come up...